# How to get multiple values of Hash based on key

Tags: perl

i am getting data from csv and storing in data in hash.From there i want to provide key and based on that key i want to get all values of Hash.There can be duplicate key that's i want all values of hash .

for ex :

```
 **SpecID           Note_Text**

 300000111166   LDPE Bottle/Jar
 300000111166   Poly-lined Steel Drum
 300000057768   Amber Glass Bottle/Jar
```

Now if i give key : 300000111166

i should get values : LDPE Bottle/Jar,Poly-lined Steel Drum.How it can be done.

Answer (score 5):

Use array references as the values of your hash. When going over your input, `push` values to the hash instead of assigning them. When retrieving hash values, remember that the hash value must be dereferenced to see the contents.

```
 while (<FH>) {
     ($key,$value) = split /\t/;
     push @{$hash{$key}}, $value;
 }
 ...
 foreach $key (keys %hash) {
     print "values for $key: ";
     print join(",", @{$hash{$key}}), "\n";
 }
```

---

Use a multi-dimensional hash. An advantage of this approach is that duplicate values won't be printed twice (or that could be a disadvantage, depending how you want to handle duplicate values)

```
while (<FH>) {
    ($key,$value) = split /\t/;
    $hash{$key}{$value}++;
}
...
foreach $key (keys %hash) {
     print "values for $key: ";
     print join(",", keys %{$hash{$key}}), "\n";
}
```

---

Use a tried-and-true solution to this problem: [the `Tie::Hash::MultiValue` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Hash::MultiValue):

```
use Tie::Hash::MultiValue;
tie %hash, 'Tie::Hash::MultiValue';
while (<FH>) {
    ($key,$value) = split /\t/;
    $hash{$key} = $value;
}
...
foreach $key (keys %hash) {
     print "values for $key: ";
     print join(",", @{$hash{$key}}), "\n";
}
```